# how to make simple quiz and button answer in telegram bot with php?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to make a simple question and the answer in multiple choice, the result what i want is like this picture : [this is picture for desired the multiple choice button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66wsO.png) 

but the result is not like what i desired this is the picture for result from my code : [this is picture for not desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AmaU.png)

and this is the code that i have tried :

```
<?php
$token = "##################################";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

$array = array(array("1","2","3"));
$btn = array("keyboard" => $array,"hide_keyboard" => true,'selective' => true,);
$reply = json_encode($btn);
$url = $website."/sendmessage?chat_id=$chatIdtext=select : &reply_markup=".$reply;
file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, maybe the result like what you want.

```
<?php
$token = "######################################";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

$name1 = 'das';
$name2 = 'dsa';
$placeId1 = '1';
$placeId2 = '2';
$keyboard = [
            'inline_keyboard' => [[['text' =>  $name1, 'callback_data' => $placeId1]], [['text' =>  $name2, 'callback_data' => $placeId2]]],
        ];

$reply = json_encode($keyboard);
$url = $website."/sendmessage?chat_id=130434215&text=select : &reply_markup=".$reply;
file_get_contents($url);
?>
```